# Payment from a website to another background running website

Tags: web, plugins, payment-gateway, webrequest

Is it possible (and legal) to have a chrome plugin feature for making a payment from a website to another website without accessing the second website? For example, skyscanner redirects the user to the air flight companies' websites. Would it be possible for the user to make the payment directly on Skyscanner without being redirected to the company's website?

Comment: It's unclear from the question what your goals are. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Is the "first website" **your** website, and the "second website" **someone else's** website? Or are you trying to create a Chrome plugin to capture payment details on someone else's website? You've specifically called out a chrome plugin. Is there a reason you're interested in chrome plugins? Or would a JS library?

Answer (score 0):

Let's clarify some assumptions:

- You're trying to improve *your own* website ("first website") by sending payment information to a 3rd party payment provider ("second website").
- You are willing to accept that *you*,  will be collecting the payment. In the example you gave, skyscrapper is just referring you to an airline and probably collecting a commission.
- You don't actually care about chrome plugins. You just care about creating a better user experience that doesn't redirect to a different website.

---

> Is it possible **(and legal)** ...

Laws will vary by country, but I'm not aware of any legal issues in the US. However, by collecting the payment yourself, you're likely going to need to pursue some level of PCI compliance. PCI compliance is generally required by contracts you'll have to sign with banks when you get a bank account that can accept deposits from the people paying you.

> making a payment from a website to another website without accessing the second website?

Some payment gateways offer libraries that will embed `<iframe>`s in your website. These `<iframe>`s point to the payment gateway and exist to collect the customer's credit card data. Here's an example from humble bundle:

[image]

They're using Stripe - and if you inspect the page, you'll see that Humble Bundle is rendering an `<iframe>` that points to some page hosted by Stripe. The benefit here is that Humble Bundle has *absolutely no exposure* to the credit card data and is able to greatly reduce any compliance headaches when certifying for the PCI compliance (they're very likely eligible to complete [SAQ-A](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2_1-SAQ-A.pdf?agreement=true&time=1561688079936)).

This type of library is probably what you're looking for.

Here's a few examples commercial products that do this:

- [Stripe - Stripe Elements](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js)
- [Authorize.net -  Accept.js](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html)
- [Braintree - Hosted Fields](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/overview/javascript/v2)
- [Adyen](https://docs.adyen.com/checkout/)
- [Square](https://developer.squareup.com/docs/payment-form/what-it-does)
- There's more that I can't possibly list here.

You almost certainly won't find a provider that will do this for free.